# Trying to check if value exists in json

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to create a script that checks for if a value exists in a json file but I keep getting a error that I don't understand and its the same no matter how I rewrite. my questions are what is the error and how could I fix it?
code snippet:

```
with open('json_file.json') as f:
     data = json.load(f)
for i in data:
   if i['hosts'] in data:
      print("it found it")
```

error message:

```
Ignoring exception in command myprofile:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 64, in myprofile
    if i['hosts'] in data:
KeyError: 'hosts'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'hosts'
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your json file and what you are trying to find? Right now your code reads every item in the `data` object, tries to find a "hosts" element inside that item, then checks whether the element it finds is a key in the original `data` object. This fails when the item doesn't contain a 'hosts' key. I doubt this is what you are trying to do. If you just want to check whether there is a 'hosts' item in the `data` object, don't use a loop — just use `if 'hosts' in data:` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `i.get('hosts', None)` instead of `i['hosts']`.

For example if your json file looks like this
`{'field1': {'someotherfield': 'xxxx'}, 'field2': {'hosts': 'host1'}}`

when the statement `for i in data:` runs it loops through `field1` & `field2`. The statement `i['hosts']` requires every field (i.e) field1, field2 in our case to have a key called as `hosts`. If some field doesn't have that key it raises `KeyError`. Instead use `i.get('hosts', None)` it would firstly check for the key named `hosts`, if it is not present it simply returns None.

P.S : If you are working with a simple dictionary, then @JaniniRami's solution should work fine for you, if you are working with a nested dictionary or json like dictionary then my solution would do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
found =  "hosts" in data 

print(found)
```

Found will return either True or False at this case.

Answer (score 0):

Only one other answer seemed to answer your 1st question. The error is that the key was not found, so it raises `KeyError`. While there are multiple ways to fix this, the probably easiest (subjective) to understand is this code snippet:

```
try:
    data = i['hosts']
except KeyError:
    #notfound
```